# Can SQL be used to return a distributed sample set?

Tags: sql, t-sql, psql

I need a sample dataset, basically to reduce the number of rows so that the sample can be loaded into one Excel sheet.

I've looked at the analytic functions and this [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3170642805938) post, but I'm not able to get the results I need, basically because I don't see my needs being able to utilize an analytical grouping.

Here's a representation of the data. Each row is unique. `Cat_No` is the primary key.

```
      CAT_NO |PROD_CODE   |DESCRIPTION |COLOR |
        SH1  |SH          |Shirt       |Blue  |
        SH2  |SH          |Shirt       |Red   |
        BT1  |BT          |Belt        |Black |
        BT4  |BT          |Belt        |Brown |
        WT1  |WT          |Watch       |Silver|
        WT6  |WT          |Watch       |Gold  |
```

Is it possible to write SQL query that will return one row with all columns for each `PROD_CODE`? If, what is it?

Hopefully there is an ANSI SQL solution as I have to use both PSQL and TSQL. Also, performance is not much of a consideration even though tables may have millions of rows. This is for one time execution to have sample data for documentation.

For example, the result could look like this:

```
      CAT_NO |PROD_CODE   |DESCRIPTION |COLOR |
        SH1  |SH          |Shirt       |Blue  |
        BT4  |BT          |Belt        |Brown |
        WT6  |WT          |Watch       |Gold  |
```

One row for each `PROD_CODE`. Any row is acceptable.

Comment: what should the result look like?

Comment: @vkp edited the question to include acceptable result.

Comment: If it doesn't matter what data you get back per prod_code you could use `row_number() over (partition by prod_code order by cat_no) as row_num` and filter the resulting set on `row_num = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't matter what data you get back per prod_code you could use `row_number() over (partition by prod_code order by cat_no) as row_num` and filter the resulting set on `row_num = 1`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT CAT_NO, PROD_CODE, DESCRIPTION, COLOR 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROD_CODE ORDER BY CAT_NO) AS row_num
  FROM TABLE
) t
WHERE t.row_num = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested and got the required results. I like your answer better than  mine because the `where` clause, I assume can be modified to return more than one sample row per `PROD_CODE`.  Is the `ORDER BY` clause required?

Comment: @Karl The `order by` is needed for row_number to work (at least in t-sql). If you want more samples per group you could change the where clause to allow for higher row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
(  select *
        , row_number() over (partition by PROD_CODE order by CAT_NO) as rn 
   from table 
)  tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: You and @jpw have the same answer of course and I know you were first, but when I originally started to look at yours, the `FROM` was missing and it threw me off.

Comment: @Karl  What ever.  I was an immediate edit and I was first.   Glad you recovered.

Answer (score 0):

And, this works as well:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM TABLE T
    WHERE T.CAT_NO IN (SELECT MAX(T1.CAT_NO) FROM TABLE T1 GROUP BY PROD_CODE)
```